# What's the difference between matching \n and \n\n?

Tags: javascript, regex

For some reason, I couldn't find this information anywhere.

Let's say I have some dummy text:

```
Line 1

Line 2

Line 3
```

What would be the difference between matching `\n` and `\n\n`?

Is it like this?

```
Line 1\n
\n
Line 2

Line 3
```

Or like this?

```
\nLine 1
\n
Line 2

Line 3
```

Or like this?

```
Line 1
\n
\n
Line 2

Line 3
```

https://regexr.com/64jeh

Comment: Is there really much of a difference between `\n` and any other character? It's only when viewing text that `\n` is treated differently

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it should be straight forward, one `\n` means one new line, two `\n\n` means two new lines, depends on use cases if you want to remove all newlines in text just use `\n+`